# JSON.stringify gives different results on different URLs

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, debugging

Tested in chrome, firefox, opera.

1. Open url https://www.patro.cz/
2. Open JS console and write: `JSON.stringify([])`
3. The output should be: `"[]"`

[image]

The problem is ...

1. Open url https://www.patro.cz/kategorie/male-domaci-spotrebice
2. Open JS console and write: `JSON.stringify([])`
3. The output should be: `"[]"` but it is `""[]""`

[image]

When I try to re-create the original object like this: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([]))` on the first URL it is an array `[]` which is correct, but on the second one it is a string `"[]"`.

My question is how to fix this. I want to get an array (correct result) on both URLs. Is this some bug in browser?

Thank you guys

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Can you send me your screenshot on the second URL ?

Comment: I think I did something wrong. The second link did return `"[]"` but `JSON.stringify` was not overrode. This is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem was that your page is using Prototype.js 1.6, which was from 10 years ago and it messes up your page's objects.

The problem was that Prototype.js adds `.toJSON` to `Array.prototype` which is very problematic (`.toJSON` instructs `JSON.stringify` how to serialize an object instance.) Remove that method and it should work fine.

```
delete Array.prototype.toJSON;
JSON.stringify([]);
```

Get rid of that library as soon as possible.